# Is it possible to have many cases for ngIF in angular 2 template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

i have a  list of months number like this:

```
months = ['1','2','3'...etc]
```

And i itterate over array in template :

```
<table  *ngFor="let month of allMonthChannel"  >
        <months *ngIf =" something "></months> 
</table>
```

The question is how i can display my months component when month value only be like 3,6,9,12. What i should i put instead "something " ? 
Thanks for answers and sory for my english :)

Comment: Are you looking for https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple solution could be using [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), granted you really just need the months 3, 6, 9 and 12:

```html
<table  *ngFor="let month of allMonthChannel"  >
    <months *ngIf="month % 3 == 0"></months> 
</table>
```

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t9ovY3EI4ZRuZ4zzaYq1?p=preview) for a working example

Comment: While you've definitely given the answer he asked for, I think mentioning the NgSwitch directive would be useful to anyone who finds this question looking for an answer that can't be solved with simple math.

Comment: Work correctly. Im new in angular 2 and typescript and i didnot came up with that i can use simply math in angular2. i am fool  :p